# Insert figure caption within same text box instead of a new text box

Tags: microsoft-word

All my floating figures are wrapped in text boxes (in order to be able to define margins through paragraph styles). When I use the "Add caption" button to create a caption for such a figure, Word adds an extra text box below the text box. This causes problems in case I need to move the figure.

Is there a way to make Word add the caption within the existing text box? I know that I can also create captions manually, e.g. by copying the auto-number field from some other caption, but I was wondering if there is a more convenient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you select a figure or picture inside a Textbox, and add a caption in Word, the Caption is inside the Textbox.

No macro is needed. Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Here is a [temporary link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/isg5snoxe1js3gf/deleteme%20caption%20inside%20textbox%20with%20figure.docx?dl=0) to the document.

When I inserted the Caption it was underneath and I had to expand the Text Box down to see the Caption.

Here is my writing on [Inserting Captions](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#Caption) and [moving them with the figure](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#MovingFigureCaption). I am using Word for Windows 365 and Word 2010.

Comment: The same also works if text is selected in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating the captions manually, but with the help of a handy macro, which adds the appropriate auto-number field after having typed "Figure" or "Table".

Here is the macro:

```
Sub InsertCaptionNumber()    
    Dim textBefore As String
    With Selection.Range
        .End = .Start
        .MoveStart wdWord, -1
        textBefore = .Text
    End With
    
    Dim captionLabel As Variant
    For Each captionLabel In CaptionLabels
        If captionLabel.Name = Trim(textBefore) Then
            Selection.Fields.Add Selection.Range, wdFieldSequence, captionLabel.Name & " \* ARABIC", False
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

With this macro bound to some keyboard shortcut, I can e.g. type <kbd>F</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>(the shortcut)</kbd>, and get the field with the correct figure number.